# MSIL Reference Manual

Tags: cil

Is there any readable, up to date (.net 4) MSIL Reference Manual?

Comment: You might try checking wikipedia, although it is not guaranteed that it is 100% correct: [List of CIL Instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a bunch of downloadable reference documents [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180615110933/https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/ecma-c-common-language-infrastructure-standards/).

Including the ECMA-335 Common Language Infrastructure documentation ([pdf](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-335.pdf)), dated June 2006, and other draft documents dated 27 March 2010.

Comment: Yes, I have that.  I use it but I think it fails "readable".  I was more hoping for something like "MSIL in a Nutshell" a la O'Reilly

Comment: @Max Yaffe - that's like asking for x86 assembly in a nutshell ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, scanning the pile of .Net, C#, ... books I own, Donis Marshall has a very good chapter on MSIL Programming in "Programming MS Visual C#2005: The Language".  It's been updated to C#2008, but not to 2010 yet.